# Include an include() in a loop

Tags: php, loops, include

I have this code to loop the data to my website:

```
$loop = Array();

# LOOP
foreach($sql->query($get_blogposts) AS $blogpost) {
    echo '<div class="blogpost-avatar" style="background-image: url('.url('images/avatars/avatar-cropped.jpg').');"></div>';

    echo '<div class="blogpost-information">';
        include(DIR_REQUIRED.'/blogpost-information.php');
    echo '</div>';

    echo '<div class="blogpost-content">';
        echo $blogpost['message'];
    echo '</div>';
}


echo implode('<hr>', $loop);
```

The problem is that I don't know how I shall put `$loop[] =` in the `foreach` loop. I have tested like this:

```
    $loop[] = '<div class="blogpost-avatar" style="background-image: url('.url('images/avatars/avatar-cropped.jpg').');"></div>

    <div class="blogpost-information">'.
        include(DIR_REQUIRED.'/blogpost-information.php')
    .'</div>

    <div class="blogpost-content">'.
        $blogpost['message']
    .'</div>';
```

But I'm getting the error message "Failed opening ... for include". I have even tested to add a dot in front of the `=` like this: `$loop[] .=` but that didn't work either.

How can I solve my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the file exists? Do you have a return statement in your include file?

Comment: Yes. The files I'm including does exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using an output buffer!

```
$loop = Array();    # LOOP
foreach($sql->query($get_blogposts) AS $blogpost) {
  $str = '';
  $str .= '<div class="blogpost-avatar" style="background-image: url('.url('images/avatars/avatar-cropped.jpg').');"></div>';

  $str .= '<div class="blogpost-information">';

  ob_start();

  include(DIR_REQUIRED.'/blogpost-information.php');
  $str .= ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();

  $str .= '</div>';

  $str .= '<div class="blogpost-content">';
  $str .= $blogpost['message'];
  $str .= '</div>';
  $loop[] = $str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$loop = array();

foreach ($sql->query($get_blogposts) as $blogpost) 
{
    ob_start();

        echo '<div class="blogpost-avatar" style="background-image: url('.url('images/avatars/avatar-cropped.jpg').');"></div>';
        echo '<div class="blogpost-information">';

        include DIR_REQUIRED.'/blogpost-information.php';

        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="blogpost-content">';
        echo $blogpost['message'];
        echo '</div>';

    $loop[] = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
}

echo implode('<hr>', $loop);

?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php

Answer (score 0):

I assumes that there is some static information stored in "blogpost-information.php" file because the way you are adding contents of file, derive me this conclusion. If my guess is right than probably following solution might work -

> $str = "";
>   if(file_exists(DIR_REQUIRED.'/blogpost-information.php')){
>        $str = fgets(DIR_REQUIRED.'/blogpost-information.php');
>      }
>   array_push($loop, "blah blah ".$str."blah blah ");